# Java Streams: Do f() for N - 1 elements and g() for N. i.e. different function for the last element

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there a way to call the Java stream API to perform a function for all but the last elements of an `Iterable` and call another on the last without splitting it into two separate calls?

This would save on two passes on the array, one for splitting the array into it's head-array and tail-element, and another to iterate those two and apply a function.

My use case is calling `repo.save(entity)` on all but the last element and `repo.saveAndFlush(entity)` on the last.

Assume I have a `Iterable<FooEntity> items;`

I'm hoping for a solution along the lines of `items.stream().???.profit(!)`

---

### Update:

Here is my class updated as per @jonsharpe 's comment:

```
public class FooWriter implements ItemWriter<FooEntityManifest> {
  private final FooRepository fooRepo;

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  @Autowired
  public FooWriter(FooRepository fooRepo) {
      this.fooRepo = fooRepo;
  }

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends FooEntityManifest> items) {
      items.forEach(fooEM -> {
          FooEntity foo = fooEM.getChangedObject();
          fooRepo.save(foo);
      });
      em.flush();
  }
}
```

As i mentioned in the comments, I'm unsure whether this injects the correct `EntityManager` so would rather use the repo only. Are my concerns valid?

P.S. I realize that my collection interface is of `List` and not `Iterable` but I was wondering about this in a general sense.

Comment: In this example, why not .save all of them then .flush after?

Comment: I'm asking for pedagogical purposes, plus the dependencies on my Class become the repository and the EntityManager and not just the repo. That's OK I guess but there is a strong reliance on the EntityManager being injected through spring correctly as the same one used to back the repository. I am uncomfortable with this but maybe someone can ease my fears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to treat all items equally like

```
items.forEach(fooEM -> fooRepo.save(fooEM.getChangedObject()));
em.flush();
```

If you want to treat the last element specially, the Stream API is not the right tool for the job. There are possible solutions, but they will be more complicated than using an other API.

E.g. considering that your starting point is a `List`:

```
if(!items.isEmpty()) {
    int last = items.size()-1;
    items.subList(0, last).forEach(fooEM -> fooRepo.save(fooEM.getChangedObject()));
    fooRepo.saveAndFlush(items.get(last).getChangedObject());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` to simulate such a behavior. E.g.:

```
list.stream()
    .reduce((a, b) -> {
                repo.save(a);
                return b;
            })
    .ifPresent(x -> repo.saveAndFlush(x));
```

But, to be completely honest, this is quite clunky, and from a maintenance point of view, you might be better off using @ jonrsharpe's suggestion in the comments - "In this example, why not .save all of them then .flush after"?

Comment: `reduce` requires an *associative* function or, in other words, does not guaranty to process all items in the encounter order.